# Fitting models to data with exponential range

Tags: modeling, nonlinear-regression

I want to create a regression model of data with exponential range (y values 2,4,8,...,512). X values are vectors of dozens...hundreds of parameters, and some of them clearly have nonlinear relation to y, some of them do not. My main interests are the low values (x* = argmin y) that I want to be able to predict accurately, whereas in the high range I don't care if the value is 512 or 256.

I have tested several different models (e.g. random forest regression, different neural network implementations, and Gaussian process regression) with and without transforming y values to log2(y) (which creates heteroscedastic variation), but the models persistently fail to predict the low values accurately. Here is an example of how the models tend to behave (this is not real data but an example I made up to illustrate how the low y values tend to have higher relative error than the intermediate/high values): [image]

Why the models behave like that, seemingly regardless of the model type I choose? What are either the most appropriate models for this kind of data, or methods for transforming it/weighing it/redefining model training procedure to improve accuracy in the low value region?

Comment: Please tell us some context. What does your Y-variable represent in real life? How many x variables (and what do they represent?) How many observations? Can you show us some plots ... without some such info pretty little we can do ...

Comment: I kind of get why models wouldn’t do a good job of predicting the low values. If the true value is 1 and you predict 2, you incur a penalty of 1. If the true value is 512 and you predict 490, you incur a penalty of 22. While you might consider the former case to be the more egregious error, of course the model is going to tighten up the predictions of large numbers!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, thank you for the comment! My y variable is a result of a physics experiment, x variables are a multitude of parameters known to affect the result. I added an example graph to clarify the problem. I'm looking for a general direction for this type of problems (what to google) rather than a solution to my exact problem. Just want to learn more (because it clearly seems I'm missing something essential here).

Comment: @Dave, thank you for the comment! That's well defined! Would you have any suggestions if these issues should normally be addressed by seeking a better transformation for y (so that it represents also the desired accuracy at different y values) or altering the model/training algorithm?